# Simplest way to merge two useState values

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-state

I have a react native hook where `trips` must be updated every time a `createdTrips` is added to the state:

```
        const [trips, setTrips] = useState([]);
        
        function fetchCreatedTrips() {
            try {
                API.graphql(graphqlOperation(onCreateTrip)).subscribe({
                    next: (result) => {
                        console.log(result);
                        const updatedTrips = [...trips, result.value.data.onCreateTrip]
                        setTrips(updatedTrips)
                    }
                })
            } catch (err) { console.log(err) }
        }
```

Now, when i first open the screen, it renders all the `trips` items of the list.
However with the current code, after i create a trip and go back to that screen, it doesn't currently return all the trips + the newly created one, but only one, that is the newly created one. How can i return all the items of the list? Sorry in advance, i'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

While setting the new state on your effect you should include the previous values of the trips. You can use the spread operator to do the same.

```
const createdTrips = [result.value.data.onCreateTrip];
setTrips([...createdTrips, ...trips]);
```

or better merge the newly created trip in the updateTrips variable and then set it as the state value,

```
const udpatedTrips = [...trips,result.value.data.onCreateTrip];
setTrips(udpatedTrips);
```

The problem in your code is you are firing those two methods at the same time and there can be race conditions, so you see random updates on the screen.

Ideally, you need to bring in some consistency in the API calls and the state update. So first fetchTrips()->then->fetchCreatedTrips(). Try the below code wherein I don't update the state immediately in fetchTrips() but rather pass on the results to fetchCreatedTrips() which completes the API call and updates the state together.

```
const [trips, setTrips] = useState([]);
    
useEffect(() => {
    fetchTrips();
  }, [])


   async function fetchTrips() {
    try {
      const tripData =  await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listTrips));
      const trips = tripData.data.listTrips.items
      fetchCreatedTrips(trips);
      
    } catch (err) { console.log(err) }
  }

function fetchCreatedTrips(fetchedTrips) {
    try {
        API.graphql(graphqlOperation(onCreateTrip)).subscribe({
            next: (result) => {
                console.log(result);
                const updatedTrips = [...fetchedTrips,...updatedTrips];
                setTrips(updatedTrips)
            }
        })
    } catch (err) { console.log(err) }
}
```

PS: Please handle exceptions correctly.

Comment: it is now showing a random number of items, sometimes it updates and sometimes not. I believe there is something wrong with my code.

Comment: I got the issue after you posted your entire code. Let me edit my solution.

Comment: thanks, it is no longer showing any list now but giving me Cannot read property X of undefined (for the item component) any idea why this can happen? Ps please check updated flatlist code

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the FlatList logic, can you please post the MyTripsPostItem code?

Comment: it seems that it's giving this error Cannot read property CreateTrip of undefined

Comment: I don't see a variable named CreateTrip in the code btw are you still facing this issue?